# How to know what bin/run-example is converted to?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running `bin/run-example ml.ImputerExample`. I know this will convert to something like `spark-submit --name MyApp --class MyMainClass --master local[2] myapplication.jar`.

But what excatly it converts to? I have take a look into `bin/run-example`, but did not find the answer. The content of `bin/run-example`

```
if [ -z "${SPARK_HOME}" ]; then
  source "$(dirname "$0")"/find-spark-home
fi

export _SPARK_CMD_USAGE="Usage: ./bin/run-example [options] example-class [example args]"
exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-submit run-example "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the command `bin/run-example ml.ImputerExample` converts to:

```
${JAVA_HOME}/jre/bin/java -cp ${SPARK_HOME}/conf/:${SPARK_HOME}/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --jars ${SPARK_HOME}/examples/jars/scopt_2.11-3.3.0.jar,${SPARK_HOME}/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar --class org.apache.spark.examples.ml.ImputerExample spark-internal
```

You can verify this by echoing logging the `exec` command in `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-class`

Answer (score 1):

Use the hidden feature of Spark **SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND** environment variable that once set to anything will print out the entire Spark command to standard output.

```
$ SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=1 ./bin/run-example hello
Spark Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/Current/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp /Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark/conf/:...
========================================
```

See [org.apache.spark.launcher.Main](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/Main.java#L56) that is eventually executed from Spark's shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

spark-submit generate a command to trigger a execution of Java. Have a look on the Spark Code.

One key entry point for the parsing

./launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:70.

Here the parameter run-example is used to define a parameter for the command builder in Spark, then you can follow up how the parameters for the execution are parsed in the same class a bit below.